# Creating custom column type

Tags: sharepoint-2013, settings, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, customcolumn

I'm creating custom column type, and i was able to implement it on my test site.  I want to learn how to add some settings/properties/configurations to this column type (sorry I'm not sure what it is exactly called for reference attaching image here)

[I want to add column's settings as in the image in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpcHF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create Editor Control for a custom Field Type Property, check below official guideline.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802857(v=office.14).aspx

Sample:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj126861(v=office.14).aspx